# How to apply properties to 3 types of input on HOVER?

Tags: html, css, input, hover

I am trying to make 3 types of `inputs` (`text`, `password`, and `number`) have a background color on `hover`.
I tried this:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=number]:HOVER {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But it only makes the `number` input have that property on `HOVER`, and for the `text` and `password`, it is applied in their regular state.

I do not want to make 3 blocks of css for each `input` type having same properties. **How can I apply the `background-color: red;` (and other possible properties) to all three types of inputs on `HOVER`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to declare each:

```
input[type=text]:hover, input[type=password]:hover, input[type=number]:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3orkpyoh/)